# Updating nested fields with Mongoose in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following query which is successful in the MongoDB CLI client but unsuccessful with its equivalent in Mongoose:

```
// MongoDB client successfully updates collection

db.col.updateOne({_id: "5f687da23a4dc9071baefd6d"}, {$set: { 'licence.count' : 5 }})

// Mongoose query which fails

Organisation.updateOne({_id: "5f687da23a4dc9071baefd6d"}, {$set: {'licence.count' : 5}})
```

The table is simply an _id with a field called licence which contains a nested document containg a count. Is there a different syntax for accessing nested fields in MongoDB as I am able to set fields at top level such as licence itself?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you're using the mongoose query?

Comment: I am running the query which mocha inside a try catch block using await so that errors are caught. When I run the query it passes with no error and fails to apply the update. I find this strange as other errors do occur. I tested this with a forced duplicate _id query

Comment: You may need to add { new: true } to tell mongoose to return the updated document after the query. So, Organisation.updateOne({_id: "5f687da23a4dc9071baefd6d"}, {$set: {'licence.count' : 5}}, {new:true})

Comment: But I don't want the new document I just want it to update?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your Mongoose query:

`{$set {'lic...`

that should be

`{$set: {'lic...`

Comment: Good catch. If that's indeed the issue, the OP should have reported an error message. Let's see what they say and if it's not a typo in the post.

Comment: This mistake only exists in the example, I have updated it. Any other possibilities ?